# How can I implement WS-Security at JQuery end?

Tags: jquery, wcf, soap, wcf-binding, wshttpbinding

I followed this codeproject [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311908/Calling-WCF-service-exposed-with-different-binding).
At the **Consuming the Service Exposed with wsHttpBinding in JQuery** section it's written that:

> A service exposed with “wsHttpBinding” binding implements WS-Security
>   of WS-* family of web service specifications. As the binding uses
>   security, the request will be rejected. The service cannot be called
>   without implementing WS-Security at JQuery end. So, in order to call
>   the service method, we have to compromise with the security.

and they are implementing a Non-secure `<wsHttpBinding>` Endpoint.

But I want my `<wsHttpBinding>` will be `<security mode="Message">`,
This off-course doesn't works and returning the following error:

> The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the
>   action
>   'http://www.enghouse.com/CosmoCom/WebAdminAPIServiceLibrary/IQueue/GetAllQueues'
>   is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired
>   security context token or because there is a mismatch between
>   bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service
>   aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from
>   aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the
>   service endpoint's binding.

If I will change this to `<security mode="None">` it works perfectly.

So my question is how can I implement `<security mode="Message">`?
What I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check out Ws.js](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/373317/Ws-js-A-Ws-implementation-for-Node-js). It is a JavaScript library that helps implement ws-security.

Personally I would only do this if I have to integrate a web client with an existing WCF service that I do not have the source code for. The overhead is too large to maintain the SOAP protocol and WCF security for a web client without any added benefit. If you control the source for this service I would provide a REST API for the web client using [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) and use SSL with HTTP basic security.